# Why was this question deleted by community?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, community-user, deleted-users, automatic-deletion

I only noticed the deletion because my answer was the accepted one. I really am not worried about the rep nor having the question re-instated. It was rather low quality so I don't even really disagree with the deletion.

What I am curious about is why it was deleted by the Community user. Was it because of flags? Because of the asker's account being deleted? Because of some other issue?

This is the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26597881/jquery-click-not-working-as-expected/26597942#26597942

Note that it is deleted, so you will need 10k rep to view it. Here is a small screenshot of the deletion messages for those who cannot view the post.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Possibly - user deletion script (related on Meta.Programmers.SE: [What roomba script went after this question](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6820/what-roomba-script-went-after-this-question)).  Key point is that regular community deletion scripts run at a set time each day.  Community deleting things at this hour, with a deleted user would suggest a different event happening.

Comment: @MichaelT - Ah, I see. Your link does contain the answer I believe. Can you repost that as an answer here with the link so I can accept it?

Comment: Too bad you spent time on it, tho you didn't lose any rep.  You could flag and ask mods to undelete if you think you can prove the question and answers have merit on their own.

Comment: @Will - Well, my answer was the accepted one so I did lose 15 rep, the checkmark was apparently deleted with the post. I mostly answered it for the OP, as a whole the question does not really add much value since it was basically a simple misunderstanding. I don't think it should be undeleted.

Comment: Huh, it wasn't marked accepted... does that get unchecked automatically on deletion?  Don't remember that happening before...

Comment: @Will http://i.imgur.com/4bljtBe.png

Comment: Yup. I know I've seen deleted questions with selected answers.  This has to be new(ish), or he unaccepted prior to removal.  Anyhow, I'll not bother your inbox more on the subject.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

When a user is deleted, the process also deletes all negatively scored posts by a user.  If that post is a question, the entire question gets deleted.

From [What EXACTLY happens when I ask to delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131665/what-exactly-happens-when-i-ask-to-delete-my-account/131666#131666)

> When you delete an account, the account is anonymized (as above), and only negatively-scored posts are deleted. All of your posts (deleted and not) just appear to come from some anonymous user who doesn't have an account anymore.

In this case, the question was likely negatively scored too, and deleted as part of the user deletion.

Comment: Yes, the question was at -2.

Comment: it's probably worth quoting a [comment](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6820/what-roomba-script-went-after-this-question#comment18430_6821) in the answer at Programmers meta: "Reminder to all: if an answer you've labored over is sitting below a downvoted, closed question... **Edit the question.** It may be deleted at any time without warning, either by users voting or automatically by various systems, until/unless it is fixed."

Comment: It'd be nice to have an override (if there isn't one already) for highly upvoted answers to such questions.

Comment: @dfeuer I can see the logic behind it, and the 'where is the threshold' problem.  A 10k+ user can cast an undelete vote on it and then having an upvoted answer will prevent the roomba from deleting it again.

Comment: @MichaelT, that only works if a 10k+ user notices. Is there any reason they would?

Comment: @dfeuer 10k aren't likely to notice it at all, unless there is a post they answered.  Non 10k users would have to go through a post to meta (aside: these deletions, like self deletions (which this is of a sort) don't show up in the 10k recently deleted listing) about disappearing rep, in chat, or with a flag on the answer they wrote.

Comment: @MichaelT, so if the answerer isn't around any more, then a very valuable answer could go right down the drain.

Comment: @dfeuer [here is the query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/243441) of questions that would be deleted if the person asking the question had their account deleted.  As [mentioned on Meta.Prog.SE](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6820/what-roomba-script-went-after-this-question#comment18430_6821), "Reminder to all: if an answer you've labored over is sitting below a downvoted, closed question... Edit the question. It may be deleted at any time without warning, either by users voting or automatically by various systems, until/unless it is fixed."

Comment: As an aside, I'd also point to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/237471/213963) (I admit it is out of context): "I'm uncomfortable with the idea of a "good answer" to a "bad question". If the answer is good and useful it implies that the question is actually a good question too. It might be expressed badly or have suffered from some initial down-votes before it was knocked into shape, but ultimately it must have some use if the answers are good." and its advice is similarly good. Fix the question if it is to be saved from various deletion processes.