# Where is the OP of this question?

Tags: support, users, accounts

Someone asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36183880/2455888) on SO and I am surprised to see that the link to the OP's profile is not available.

This happens generally when a question is migrated from another Stack Exchange website and the OP does not have an account on SO.

Comment: [And like that... he's gone](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V1tmkAFb_Os).

Comment: @MarounMaroun; Hahahahaaaa. Good one!

Comment: I don't really care about the OP... but how can this question gather 21 upvotes in 2 days? Something is wrong here.

Comment: @Trilarion; There is always supposed to be something wrong with people who try to dig out the things behind the curtain.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The user had an account but about 10 minutes after asking the question, they self-deleted their account which destroyed the link to the user profile.

Comment: [that's why it's important to downvote low quality questions quickly](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276153/839601). By the way, if this user re-creates their account, will system consider them totally clean and let them drop more questions like that? I mean, [anti-recidivism-system](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anti-recidivism-system) kicks in only when account is already blocked at the moment of deletion, right?

Comment: @gnat: I guess I'm insane because that strikes me as a better-than-average question. It contains the code that reproduces that problem and it seems like something a beginner might reasonably be confused about, and for which good answers can be provided.

Comment: @JamesKPolk yeah. This is concrete, clear, well written and easy to understand question that any debugger will be happy to answer to

Comment: I have a feeling that if this question was asked on this site 6-7 years ago, it would have been massively up-voted by this time. You see those kinds of question every now and then.

Comment: The main problem with the question is that it include "... and how I can fix it", when there is no real way to know what it's trying to do. If the question was just "why does it get to zero" then that would be fine.

Comment: @Matt; If he knew that it can't be fixed then of course he wouldn't have asked that.

Comment: @Alex: I must admit being surprised at the score of the question too, I don't see any issue with simple questions. Maybe it could be massaged a bit, but a quick edit by anyone who's dissatisfied would be far better than a downvote. Or maybe... a close as duplicate?

Comment: Surely there's a canonical question about integer overflow in C that this could have been (and still can be) dupehammered to, right?