# Why did Community delete this upvoted question with an upvoted answer?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, deleted-users

A [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53210791/1521179) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7wfJ.png)) was asked yesterday. It received two upvotes and an answer with six upvotes. According to the post timeline, the user was destroyed. This caused the question to be deleted by Community. But why?

- [Why was this question deleted by community?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276150/1521179) seems similar but there the question had a negative score.
- [Why was this question with upvoted answers deleted?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/376163/1521179) involves a DMCA takedown, and the question is marked as deleted by a mod rather than by community.
- [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/229223) explains:

  > 11. The system will automatically delete any post with a negative score when its owner's account is deleted, unless the post is a question that has at least one positively-scored answer. (This doesn't apply on meta sites.)
  > 12. The system will automatically delete any post, regardless of score or answers to questions, when its owner's account is destroyed (only done for spammers and blatant trolls).

  [What EXACTLY happens when I ask to delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131665/229223) confirms that destroying accounts is reserved for spammers.

  Yet the deleted question does not feature spamming or blatant trolling.

→ Was the deletion of this question just (unintended) fallout from account destruction by unrelated moderator action, or is the guidance cited above about account destruction out of date, e.g. due to GDPR compliance?

Comment: can you post an image of the question for those without 10K

Comment: Per [How can I delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7979/369403), questions with a score of 1 or less that otherwise meet the roomba criteria also get deleted, but that doesn't explain this one. GDPR also can't really explain this one, since if it's not personal information it's unaffected, and if it's personal information, there's no _hide and mark as deleted_ in the GDPR, if personal information needs to be deleted it needs to be fully deleted without any way to view or recover it

Comment: More strange things going on there, the answer to that question has _show 1 more comment_ beneath it, that persists when reloading the page, but there's no comment to be found.

Comment: I've pinged the mod involved here as there's probably some background as to what happened I'm not aware of. @ErikvonAsmuth yeah... that's a deleted comment from the OP - some corner case glitch that crops up now and then - wouldn't worry about it :)

Comment: What is GDPR please?

Comment: @GeorgeJempty [GDPR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Data_Protection_Regulation) is a comprehensive privacy legislation by the European Union that e.g. applies whenever personal data from persons in Europe is collected/stored/processed. It includes a “right of erasure”. Leading up to it's deadline of May 25th earlier this year, many websites incl. Stack Overflow updated their approach to privacy so I thought maybe using account destruction instead of deletion could have been part of that.

Comment: What baffles me is why it hasn't been [marked as a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/627661/692942) already.

Comment: Appears I was wrong about the duplicate, guess i’m just surprised something like that hasn’t been asked before.

Comment: @amon A bit unrelated but my understanding of point #12 in your quote is that all good/upvoted posts will be deleted if their owner's account is destroyed for being a spammer (e.g., started spamming recently in different posts). If that's the case, isn't this a content loss as well? and if it means that only the spam posts get deleted, am I the only one who thinks the wording needs to be changed?

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed As BoltClock mentions below, this is the first time in like forever that spammer destruction led to some noticeable content loss. Changing the rules for such an outlier seems excessive. For abusive accounts you cannot rely on the post's votes to detect valuable content because they might have used sock puppets or vote rings.

Comment: Hmm! Makes sense now.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

This question was posted by a user currently serving a suspension, who created a suspension-evasion account to post it. Deleting the user caused the question to be deleted as well.

I've undeleted it, as it has a pretty decent answer that clearly took some time and effort.

Comment: oh, cool, that explains everything :) Thanks for enforcing the suspension, and for the undeletion!

Comment: Didn't we recently change how the system works regarding this to prevent this kind of content loss from happening? See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199860/a-question-should-not-be-deleted-by-the-user-deletion-algorithm-if-it-has-upvote

Comment: @TylerH that applies to user deletion but not user destruction, where the latter is reserved for abuse. So the system is working as intended, though suboptimally in this case. See also [What is the difference between a deleted user and a “destroyed” user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/88996/229223), and the quote in my question here.

Comment: So it sounds then like destroying the user was not the appropriate action here, but rather deletion should have occurred instead.

Comment: @TylerH No, destruction was 100% correct. While the content of the question was fine, the *act of posting* that question was abuse. The sole reason of the account's existence was abusing the system (circumventing a suspension). When I posted this meta question, I was just confused by the missing link in the chain of events “ok question → ??? → user destroyed”.

Comment: @amon Both methods will delete the account. If destruction was correct and the question shouldn't exist due to said abuse, then meagar shouldn't have undeleted the post. Which person do you think made the wrong choice, Meagar or the other mod? It must be one of them.

Comment: @TylerH Destroying the account also blocks the IP from creating new accounts to continue circumventing the ban, which was desirable in this case. There is no 3rd option to destroy an account and blacklist its IP while still leaving the account's content alone. This is an outlier and not a black-and-white, right-or-wrong situation.

Comment: @meagar Time for a feature request, then...

Comment: @TylerH: Meh, defined exception handler handled the exception, WAI, no new code needed.

Comment: "... who created a suspension-evasion account ..." One might think about extending the suspension.

Comment: Interesting. It seems this explains what happened to [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52983138/2751851), whose deletion caught me by surprise.

Comment: @NathanTuggy The entire thread here is evidence to the contrary.

Comment: @TylerH: This is the first time in years, if not ever, that we've had to restore a question that was asked by a ban-evasion account because it received a good answer.

Comment: @meagar You can also delete with the "no longer welcome" option, which *also* blocks IPs and records a 14-day suspension in the account's name, but doesn't delete all posts (only those deleted upon normal user deletion).