# Why is this deleted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions, moderators

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57101276/can-anyone-explain-this-double-pointer-to-2d-array-line-what-exactly-is-it-doin

- The question has not recieved any downvotes.
- There are 2 very detailed answers.
- No duplicates have been suggested.

Votes received:

- 1 unclear vote
- 2 too broad votes

Comment: I was going to suggest [account destruction](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/376440/2751851), but it seems that is performed by the Community user. Still. my guess is that similar moderation reasons are at play.

Comment: The question received 4 downvotes, actually.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While the question and answers may look fine at first glance, I have taken a closer look at moderator-only details and have verified that this question and user was appropriately deleted for reasons of moderation. No further explanation is necessary as we do not publicly disclose & discuss actions of user accounts.

Comment: Thanks for checking. Your answer is sufficient. For someone who spent effort on producing an answer, it would be great to get more info, than just that the question is deleted.